# How can one take a subset of words that do not have letters in specific locations?

Tags: r, stringr

Having trouble getting my head around this one, but I sense the answer uses `stringr::str_subset`.

Here's an example of what I'm string to achieve:

```
word_list <- c("amber", "flora", "glide", "quake", "slant")
word_neg <- "aside"
word_list_pruned <- some_function(word_list, word_neg)

> word_list_pruned
> c("flora", "slant")
```

I want to take a list of words, `word_list`, and a word, `word_neg` (here, "aside"), and I want to remove all words in `word_list` that have letters that match/are in the same place as in `word_neg`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a regex approach.  Given the negative word `aside`, we can build the following regex alternation:

```
^(?:a....|.s...|..i..|....d.|....e)$
```

Any word which does *not* match this alternation should be retained as a match.

```r
word_list <- c("amber", "flora", "glide", "quake", "slant")
word_neg <- "aside"

patterns <- sapply(seq_along(1:5), function(x) {
    paste0(strrep(".", x - 1), substr(word_neg, x, x), strrep(".", nchar(word_neg) - x))
})
pattern <- paste0("^(?:", paste(patterns, collapse="|"), ")$")
word_list_pruned <- word_list[!grepl(pattern, word_list)]
word_list_pruned

[1] "flora" "slant"
```

The complex string manipulation inside the call to `sapply()` is generating the regex alternation.  We simply start off with `.....`, and then add back one letter from the negative input word.

Comment: This works! It really feels like there should be a stringr-friendly way to do this with less formatting upfront, but this response gives me a few new ideas.

Comment: If I wanted to do the inverse, meaning if I had a string like "s...." and ".l..." and I wanted to scan the dictionary for words that match both patterns, eg get words like slash, slate, slant back, how would I modify the above? Sorry, I'm awful at regex.

Comment: Won't that give you words with "s...." OR ".l..."?

Comment: `match both patterns` ... what are the patterns?

Comment: The patterns would be something like "s...." and ".l...". So I want all words from the dictionary that start with "sl", but I want to be able to specify it as "s...." and ".l..." so that I can add to it easily.

Comment: Starts with `sI` is `^sI` or maybe `^sI.*$`

Answer (score 1):

```
word_list <- c("amber", "flora", "glide", "quake", "slant")
word_neg <- "aside"

any_uncommon_letters <- function(word,wn){
  word_split <- strsplit(word,split = "")[[1]]
  wn_split <- strsplit(wn,split = "")[[1]]
  !any(mapply(identical,word_split,wn_split))
}

some_function <- function(wl,wn){
  wl[sapply(wl,\(x)any_uncommon_letters(x,wn))]
}

word_list_pruned <- some_function(word_list, word_neg)
word_list_pruned
```

Answer (score 1):

And a relatively hairbrained

```
word_list <- c("amber", "flora", "glide", "quake", "slant")
word_neg <- "aside"

word_mtx = matrix(unlist(strsplit(word_list, split = '')), nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)
word_neg_ord = as.vector(1:5)
zeros = vector(mode = 'logical', length= 5L)
for (i in 1:5) {
zeros[i] <- 0 %in% (word_neg_ord - match(rle(unlist(strsplit(word_neg, split = '')))$values, rle(word_mtx[i, ])$values))
 }
word_list[!zeros]
[1] "flora" "slant"
```

inelegant in all respects, from a faulty brain.